# Hiding the menubar in WxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to find a way to hide the menubar when the mouse isnt over it, i know i could get the mouse xy position and check if its in a certain area but im having no luck hiding the menubar itself. 
My code:

```
class HelloFrame(wx.Frame):
    images = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        # ensure the parent's __init__ is called
        super(HelloFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

        # create a panel in the frame
        pnl = wx.Panel(self)

        # create a menu bar
        self.makeMenuBar()

        # and a status bar
        #self.CreateStatusBar()
        #self.SetStatusText("Welcome to wxPython!")


    def makeMenuBar(self):

        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        helloItem = fileMenu.Append(-1, "&Load Backround Image")
        fileMenu.AppendSeparator()
        exitItem = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT)
        helpMenu = wx.Menu()
        aboutItem = helpMenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT)
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(fileMenu, "&File")
        #menuBar.Append(OptionsMenu, "&Options") TBM
        menuBar.Append(helpMenu, "&Help")

        # Give the menu bar to the frame
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        # Finally, associate a handler function with the EVT_MENU event for
        # each of the menu items. That means that when that menu item is
        # activated then the associated handler function will be called.
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OpenImage, helloItem)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit,  exitItem)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, aboutItem)



    def OnExit(self, event):
                self.Close(True)

    def OnAbout(self, event):
        wx.MessageBox("Test",
                      "About",
                      wx.OK|wx.ICON_INFORMATION)

    def OpenImage(self, event):
        with wx.FileDialog (None, "Choose image", wildcard="PNG files (*.png)|*.png", style=wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST) as fileDialog:
            if fileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
                return       # the user changed their mind
            else:
                # Gets rid of other images
                for i in self.images:
                    i.Destroy()
                    self.images.remove(i)

                # Displays image and adds image object to [self.images]
                ImageName = fileDialog.GetPath()
                png = wx.Image(ImageName, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
                self.images.append(wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, png, (0, 0), (png.GetWidth(), png.GetHeight())))
                print(ImageName)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frm = HelloFrame(None, title='FileHeader Test')
    frm.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

ive tried just adding menubar.Hide() in the function makemenubar but to no avail
ive also tried self.Hide() in the same area but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I should start by saying that I don't recommend that you do this.
It's non-standard and could confuse.
It's expensive cpu-wise for no obvious benefit.

That said, here is one way of doing it, using `Show`, `Hide` and `EVT_MOTION`.
The issue is that once it is hidden/removed, the next mouse **OVER** doesn't happen because it is no longer there. As you suppose, we can assign a territorial range where we suppose it would be. If the cursor strays into that zone, the menu can be shown or hidden.

```
import wx

class HelloFrame(wx.Frame):
    images = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        # ensure the parent's __init__ is called
        super(HelloFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        # create a panel in the frame
        pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        pnl2 = wx.Panel(self)
        pnl.SetBackgroundColour("green")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(pnl,1, wx.EXPAND,10)
        sizer.Add(pnl2,1, wx.EXPAND,10)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        # create a menu bar
        self.makeMenuBar()

        # and a status bar
        #self.CreateStatusBar()
        #self.SetStatusText("Welcome to wxPython!")
        pnl.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.MenuPos)


    def makeMenuBar(self):

        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        helloItem = fileMenu.Append(-1, "&Load Backround Image")
        fileMenu.AppendSeparator()
        exitItem = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT)
        helpMenu = wx.Menu()
        aboutItem = helpMenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT)
        self.menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        self.menuBar.Append(fileMenu, "&File")
        self.menuBar.Append(helpMenu, "&Help")

        # Give the menu bar to the frame
        self.SetMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.menuBar.Hide()
        # Finally, associate a handler function with the EVT_MENU event for
        # each of the menu items. That means that when that menu item is
        # activated then the associated handler function will be called.
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OpenImage, helloItem)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit,  exitItem)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, aboutItem)

    def MenuPos(self, event):
        x, y = event.GetPosition()
        if y <= 2:
            self.menuBar.Show()
        if y >= 3:
            self.menuBar.Hide()
        event.Skip()

    def OnExit(self, event):
                self.Close(True)

    def OnAbout(self, event):
        wx.MessageBox("Test",
                      "About",
                      wx.OK|wx.ICON_INFORMATION)

    def OpenImage(self, event):
        with wx.FileDialog (None, "Choose image", wildcard="PNG files (*.png)|*.png", style=wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST) as fileDialog:
            if fileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
                return       # the user changed their mind
            else:
                # Gets rid of other images
                for i in self.images:
                    i.Destroy()
                    self.images.remove(i)

                # Displays image and adds image object to [self.images]
                ImageName = fileDialog.GetPath()
                png = wx.Image(ImageName, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
                self.images.append(wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, png, (0, 0), (png.GetWidth(), png.GetHeight())))
                print(ImageName)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frm = HelloFrame(None, title='FileHeader Test')
    frm.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image][image]

Comment: Hmm weird i tried this but the menubar still dosn't seem to hide, must be a windows thing since thats what im using...

Comment: Print the data in `MenuPos` to ensure you know a: the event is firing b: the values are what you expect. `print()` is a highly under rated debugging tool these days, once upon a time it was all we had. :-)

Comment: I set it to print after any instance of `self.menuBar.Hide()` and it gets called but nothing is hidden, ill have to try compiling it on a port of linux and see if it works there

Comment: I'd include the value of `y` just to be sure. My code runs on Mint/Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: On Windows and Mac the native menubar is a little more tightly integrated with the frame than on other platforms, so we have less control over it.

Comment: Makes sense, would it just be better if i then made my own  "menubar" of sorts that mimicks the one that would be used?

Comment: Set up another test to print out the y like Rolf suggested and it seems that 0 is the top of the green even when the menubar is there, the green is just being placed under the menubar

Comment: You can use a toolbar as a menubar and show or hide it whenever you want.

Comment: I would expect 0 to always be the top of the green panel because the `EVT_MOTION` is bound to `pnl`, that's how it knows it is straying into the area where a menubar would be.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense seems like an OS thing, looking into it Toolbars seem right down my alley with what i need @DanA.S.  Thanks!